# Pegar Capa Facebook API SDK JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-sdk

Estou tentando pegar a capa do Facebook do usuário logado, mas não estou tendo sucesso.

```
FB.login(function(response){
if(response.authResponse){
    FB.api('/me', function(fb){
        var email   = fb.email;
        var nasc    = fb.birthday;
        var nome    = fb.name;
        var genero  = fb.gender;
        var local   = fb.hometown;
        var idUser  = fb.id;

        FB.api('/'+idUser+'?fields=source', function(resp){
            console.log(resp);
            return false;
        });
```

Estou fazendo como está na documentação do Facebook, mas não dá certo.

> ```
> Object {error: Object}
>
> error: Object
>
> code: 100
>
> message: "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (source) on node type (User)"
>
> type: "OAuthException"
> ```

---

Consegui. Coloquei **cover** no Parâmetro. Mas não tem na Doc. Ou eu li errado.

```
FB.api('/'+idUser+'/?fields=cover', function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Responde com a tua solução à tua pergunta e aceita essa resposta para isto ficar com solved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui. Coloquei `cover` (capa) no Parâmetro. Mas não tem na Doc. Ou eu li errado.

```
FB.api('/'+idUser+'/?fields=cover', function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
    return false;
});
```